# React Native TypeScript error: Property 'calcYOffset' does not exist on type 'ScrollView'

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a ref of a `ScrollView`:

```
const childRef = React.useRef<null | ScrollView>(null);

<ScrollView
  onScroll={() => {
    childRef.current?.calcYOffset();
  }}
```

However `calcYOffset` gives me this error:

> TS2339: Property 'calcYOffset' does not exist on type 'ScrollView'.

The ref is attached in a child component:

```
const containerViewRef = React.useRef<View>(null);

React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      calcYOffset: () => {
        containerViewRef.current?.measure(
          (
            x: any,
            y: any,
            width: any,
            height: any,
            pageX: any,
            pageY: React.SetStateAction<number>,
          ) => {
            setViewYPosition(pageY);
          },
        );
      },
    }));
```

Comment: Where do you attach `myRef`, where does `childRef` come from and where have you defined `calcYOffset` ?

Comment: @MarekLisik Ive updated my question.

Comment: Can you also show where `childRef` is defined and where do you assign it to a component?

Comment: @MarekLisik Sorry I had a mistake in my question, Ive updated it again.

Comment: Where do you assign your refs to components, though? There should be a eg. <SomeComponent ref={childRef} ... />. Maybe post a bit more code for context (at least including where you define component and ref, where you assign ref, where you use ref etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typescript error is caused by `const childRef = React.useRef<null | ScrollView>(null);` Instead of `<null | ScrollView>`, you should specify the type of your custom component (the one that uses `useImperativeHandle`). You can do this like so:

```
type Handles = {
  calcYOffset: () => void;
}

type Props = { ... your custom component props };

const CustomComponent: React.RefForwardingComponent<Handles, Props> = // your component

// then usage:
const childRef = React.useRef<CustomComponent>(null);
```